# Ignore overflow:hidden in table cell content

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table

I have a div with some content that needs to be placed before the table cell (to the left of the cell) in which it is positioned. The positioning works but the issue is that the table is wrapped by a div that has overflow: hidden property, so this div with the content I mentioned gets placed correctly but is not visible. Is there a way for this div to be positioned like this while being visible?

This is what I currently have:

```css
.padding {
  padding-left: 100px;
}

.container {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
}

td {
  position: relative;
}

.content {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  left: -50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="padding">
  <div class="container">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="content">
          </div>
          <p>Text</p>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: there's no way to revert the container overflow:hidden behaviour on a child element. You could do this (horrible) positioning: https://jsfiddle.net/5cyatvzL/ but of course it only "works" for the topmost table cell.